# JavaScript regular expression with global match help needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to JavaScript and have a question about regular expressions. I have the following code:

```
var patt3=new RegExp(/(July|August)\s+\d{1,2}(\s|,)\d{4}/g);
var str3 = "August                               12,1988";
var match3 = str3.match(patt3);
document.write(match3.toString() + "<br/>");
```

The output is: August 12,1988

Here is the same code but with the 'g' removed from the end of the RegExp:

```
var patt3=new RegExp(/(July|August)\s+\d{1,2}(\s|,)\d{4}/);
var str3 = "August                               12,1988";
var match3 = str3.match(patt3);
document.write(match3.toString() + "<br/>");
```

The output becomes: August 12,1988,August,,

From the definitions that I've found on the web, 'g' is supposed to match all occurrences of the patterns. But I'm still kind of confused as to what effect 'g' has on the code.

I would greatly appreciate any clarifications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The crucial difference is that the `string.match` method is [defined](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.10) to have a different behavior if the regex patter is global or not.

If the pattern is global, an array with all the matches. In your case you there is only one match but you can see the difference with an example like

```js
let matches = "aaaa".match(/a(a)/g); 
console.log(matches) // returns ["aa", "aa"]
```

If the pattern is not global, however, the method return an array corresponding to the first match found. The array contains the full matched string in the first position and the captures in the other positions. The captures are the bits of the regex delimited by parenthesis. Again, you can see the difference with that example:

```
"aaaa".match(/a(a)/g); // returns ["aa", "a"]
```

---

Finally, I would just like to point out some minor issues with your code.

First of all, you don't need to use the `new Regexp` constructor here. Just use the regex literal directly

```
var patt3 = /(July|August)\s+\d{1,2}(\s|,)\d{4}/g
```

Secondly, don't blindly "toString" things. In your case you are applying that method to an array and that's why you get your weird results.

Finally, learn to use the developer tools, including the debugger and console.log. Its much better than abusing document.write and alert in terms of expressiveness and productivity.

```
console.write(match3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`g` only matches all occurrences of the *entire* pattern.  It is not analogous to matching groups like PHP's `preg_match_all`.  Without `g`, it only matches the first occurrence of the pattern (`matches[0]`) and all matched groups are the other array elements.

If you wanted to get nested matches as well, you can use the concepts described by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/) to do so:

```
str3.replace(patt3, function () {
    //This is the first captured group in all matches iterated over
    console.log(arguments[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on `String.match`:

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as [regexp.exec(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
>
> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

In the second example, the first element of the array is the match, while the others are capturing groups. With `g`, each element would be a different match.